# http://localhost/myphpadmin/index.php only shows code

Tags: php, mysql, apache

- I installed Apache onto my C: drive. (C:/Apache).
- I then installed phpmyadmin and placed it inside a folder (htdocs) inside C:/Apache.

I followed a youtube installation example for Apache. When it asked me my domain name and server, I copied what the tutorial said to put, which was "localhost" for both fields.

After both Apache and phpmyadmin had been installed and set up, I tried accessing phpmyadmin, but all I got was a lot of code.

I am wondering, if, when I was installing Apache, if, I should have typed bravehost.com or my bravehost server name, instead of localhost.

When I try to access the Phpmyadmin login page (index.php), I only get a page full of code instead of the login page.

How can i do this ?

Comment: 1. Check if PHP is installed 2. CHeck if `<?` tags are enabled on php.ini

Comment: @user3493267  How you try accessing phpmyadmin ?

Comment: The name of the server has got no relevance, localhost is the way to say "this machine"; may you please paste here the "lot of code" you've got?

Comment: You using windows or linux? If windows i would highly recommend to uninstall appache and phpmyadmin and instead use wamp server(that is free). According to my thought `http://localhost/myphpadmin/index.php` can not be opened until appache is running on your system. Neither the code nor the actual page. make sure you are really writnig this URl to your browser?

Comment: It'd be so much easier if you'd just download something that does this all for you, like XAMPP or some other options.

Comment: create a file called phpinfo.php and put "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" inside. If you see a page with php informations you should be able to use phpmyadmin, if not you should install the lastest php version and enable it on apache2 configuration.

Comment: If I had have known about XAMPP before I started downloading the individual components, I would have definitely gone with this option. Even now, it sounds like the way to go, but I could not get XAMPP to run just now. Perhaps it's because I already have APACHE and PHPMYADMIN installed. I tried uninstalling Apache, but it is not in my programs file, but in my C:/ drive and there is no uninstall button. At this point I am trying to decipher which file from windows.php.net to download for windows 7, 64-bit operating system. TY 4 ur help.

Answer (score 1):

PhpMyAdmin will only work if you have PHP installed and linked to Apache as a recognized plugin by editing the httpd.conf file within Apache. If you have not done this, the browser has no way of knowing how to parse the PHP code. I advise directly downloading and using a WAMP Stack (like Zend, XAMPP or WAMPServer) which would have PHP, Apache, MySQL and phpmyadmin pre-configured. Would be easy for you to begin with.

Comment: I did not realize that I needed PHP (something separate from Phpmyadmin) installed in order for Phpmyadmin to work. Thank you. Unfortunately, I have tried installing PHP just now, and it will not install. I believe I may have chosen the wrong file. It is hard for me to decipher which file I need to download for windows 7, 64-bit operating system. Any help you can give me as to which file I need to download at the website windows.php.net would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you are trying to get php for Windows 64 bit, it depends on whether you are installing on the Apache build from the apache.org website or not. Just look for a Thread Safe x64 build on windows.php.net. Note that the php website states that the newer VC9 and VC11 builds won't work on the standard Apache binaries. I don't know about this but I've read that the Thread Safe binaries are supposed to work regardless. I've myself been using WAMPServer and I still recommend this as the way to go. Good luck though.

Comment: Note that you'll still need to install MySQL separately if you insist on a manual installation for phpmyadmin to work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install php
2. Enable php and check through phpinfo()
3. Isntall mysql
4. Install phpmyadmin

After installation by default pma url is localhost/phpmyadmin (or what eve you setuped while installation). Remember that pma is only php scripts (it's not soft as apache\mysql\php).

If you see php code on pages it means that php is not working and apache give you 'raw' code. Re-check that your php is enabled and is working.

Comment: Thank you for your help. At this time, I would like to install php. At the website: php.net, can you tell me which file I should choose to download for windows 7, 64-bit operation system?

Comment: Search something like this one http://lifeofageekadmin.com/how-install-apache-2-4-php-5-4-and-mysql-5-5-21-on-windows-7/